# Generate CMAKE targets as a function of a parameter

Tags: cmake

I have a library, which I currently define using `add_library`, which has variants that can be configured as a function of `target_compile_definitions` and selecting different source files. The selection currently depends on a name. For example, the following is the library configuration named `23x35`:

```
add_library(my_library_23x35 src/my_library.cpp src/my_variant_23x35.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(my_library_23x35 PRIVATE LIB_TYPE=my_library_23x35)
```

I'd like other projects (users of my_library, with their own CMakeLists.txt) to create the definition of the variant they need, such as `generate_my_library("23x35")` which should produce the same result as having added the `add_library` definition above in the library CMakeLists.txt. This way different user projects can select new variants without needing a CMakeLists.txt modification. (This is useful because the variant generation can also be automated in the future.)

Is this possible? Could you point me to some examples of this cmake usage?

Comment: Just define `generate_my_library` as a function or macro with corresponding body. What is a problem in such definition?

Answer (score 1):

A [function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html) or a [macro](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html) can be used to accomplish this.

The [`CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html) variable will contain the path where the function was defined [thanks go to commenter @fabian who pointed out that a solution relying on project variables will be less robust].

Here's an example with a function. It takes an argument called `size` that can be set to strings like "25x25". Of course, the respective files have to exist.

```
function (generate_my_library size)
    add_library(
        my_library_${size}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR}/src/my_library.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR}/src/my_variant_${size}.cpp
    )
    target_compile_definitions(my_library_${size} PRIVATE LIB_TYPE=my_library_${size})
endfunction()
```

Comment: This looks good to me, thank you. The function `generate_my_library` will be used at a different project, so the paths may not be correct. For example, my_library could be added to a larger project through `add_subdirectory`, and then the paths will not match.

Comment: I recommend avoiding the use of the `project` to introduce a variable to use for determining absolute paths. This will result in the current source directory being used. You won't be able to use this kind of logic in a cmake script file unless this file happens to be placed in the same directory including the script file. If available you should use [`CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR.html) instead; if not, set a global property or cache variable to `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` instead before the function definition.

Comment: @fabian thank you for your comment. I read the question as if there was already a 'project` in place. Using your suggestion gives a simpler, more general and more robust solution. I edited my answer accordingly.